# Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to develop a Register and Login App. I am using android studio 2.2 RC.
Wamp server is used for the server and database.

I am getting >>> Value br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray" each time.<<<

Its confusing.

Please help me.

// Register activity class//

```
package com.example.reean.guidetour;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

public class Register_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button reg_bn;
EditText Name, Email, UserName, Password, ConPassword;
String name, email, username, password, conpass;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
String reg_url = "http://192.168.0.104/register.php";


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_);
    reg_bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    ConPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword_confirm);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register_Activity.this);

    reg_bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = Name.getText().toString();
            email = Email.getText().toString();
            username = UserName.getText().toString();
            password = Password.getText().toString();
            conpass = ConPassword.getText().toString();


            if (name.equals("") || email.equals("") || username.equals("") || password.equals("") || conpass.equals("")) {

                builder.setTitle("Something went wrong!");
                builder.setMessage("Fill all blank fields");
                displayAlert("Input_Error");

            }
            else

            {
                if (!(password.equals(conpass)))
                          {
                             builder.setTitle("Something went wrong!");
                             builder.setMessage("Password Mismatched!");
                              displayAlert("Input_Error");
                          }

                else {
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, reg_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                                String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                                builder.setTitle("Server Response ");
                                builder.setMessage(message);
                                displayAlert(code);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }
                    ) {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("name", name);
                            params.put("email", email);
                            params.put("user_name", username);
                            params.put("password", password);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    MySingleton.getmInstance(Register_Activity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
                }
            }


                    };
                                                                });
                                                }


            public void displayAlert(final String code)

            {
                 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


              if (code.equals("Input_Error")) {
                  Password.setText("");
                  ConPassword.setText("");

              } else if (code.equals("Register_Success")){

                  startActivity(new Intent(Register_Activity.this,Login_Activity.class));
                  //finish();

              }

              else if (code.equals("Register_Failed"))
              {
                  Name.setText("");
                  Email.setText("");
                  UserName.setText("");
                  Password.setText("");
                  ConPassword.setText("");
              }

          }
                     });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

// PHP codes for register//

```
<?php

require "init,php";

$name =$_POST["name"];

$email =$_POST["email"];

$user_name =$_POST["user_name"];

$password =$_POST["password"];


$sql = "select * from user_info where email like '".$email."';";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result>0)
{
    $code = "Register_Failed";
    $message = "User already exist... ";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"meesage"=>$message));

    echo json_encode($response);

}

else
{
    $sql = "insert into user_info        values('".$name."','".$email."','".$user_name."','".$password."');";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   $code = "Register_Success";
   $message = "Thank you. Now you can login... ";
   array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));

    echo json_encode($response);
}


mysqli_close($con);





?>`
```